# Post an Array of Objects via JSON from a form -ASP.Net MVC2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2

I trying to post an array of objects when a form is post, but I always gets an empty list in the controller

JavaScript

```
function defineuser(userList) {
   var user = null;
var userAppModuleItemList = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < userList.length; i++){
        values = userList[i].split(",");
        user = {
            ID: values[0],
            Name: values[1],
            LastName: values[2]
        };
     userAppModuleItemList.push(user );
    }

    $("#userList").val(userAppModuleItemList);
};
```

View

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateUser", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "userForm" }))
  {%>
<%=Html.Hidden("userList")%>
...
<%}%>
```

Contoller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateUser(List<UserDTO> userList)
{
    // The userList is null
}
```

User Class definition

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

try `traditional : true` to post array object

```
$.ajax({ 
      type: "POST",
      url: "<%= Url.Action("MyAction","Controller")%>",
      datatype: "json",
      traditional: true,
      data: { userList : arrayOfValues }              
 });
```

Comment: How do I use this inside the 'form'? I mean, when the 'form' is post